# Best answer contest: Second quarter of 5777

Tags: discussion, status-completed, answer-contest

**This contest is over. The winners are announced [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4323/best-answer-contest-winners-second-quarter-of-5777).**

This post is locked to freeze the voting.

---

Did you see an answer on Mi Yodeya in the past few months that you thought was really great? Let's have a contest to help you tell everyone about it!

**Please link to an answer which was created in Tevet - Adar, 5777 (from December 30th, 2016 through March 27th, 2017) and which you think deserves an additional reward. Only one entry per answer will be valid. For multiple favorites submit separate answers to this post.**

Here is a data query to help with the decision making process:

[Answers with most votes from 2nd quarter of 5777](http://data.stackexchange.com/judaism/query/626662/answers-with-best-score-created-in-5777-q2?Count=50)

Otherwise you can chose your own favorite answer which didn't get the limelight or needed more appreciation. Answer can be from you or from someone else. (Yes, [purim-torah-in-jest](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/purim-torah-in-jest) answers are eligible.)

[image: 300-point Bounty button]

The answer linked in the highest voted answer to this meta post will receive a bounty of 300 points after completion of the event on May 5th, 2017. In case of a tie, the distinction will be shared, and the prize will be split.

---

<sup>Concept and words borrowed from [Movies.SE](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/rewards-for-the-best-answer-from-the-4th-quarter-of-2016).</sup>

Comment: See also the contest for the [third quarter](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4310/best-answer-contest-third-quarter-of-5777). At DoubleAA's suggestion, I've opened nominations for that one already, so you can link to great answers as you see them.

Comment: I've extended the contest period for another three days.

Comment: If we'd like to nominate multiple answers, should we do so in one post, or multiple ones?

Comment: @DonielF Multiple.

Answer (score 3):

[mevaqesh's answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/80705/2) to [Source that hearing the Megillah does not require Hebrew understanding?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/80703/source-that-hearing-the-megillah-does-not-require-hebrew-understanding) traces the rule in question from the Mishna down to the Shulchan Aruch, providing clear references, quotations with translations, and on-point, succinct explanations along the way. It's an exemplary response to a "what is the source for ..." question.

Answer (score 3):

[HodofHod's answer](//judaism.stackexchange.com/a/79713) about the Touro Synagogue's trap door shows a good deal of research into authoritative sources.

Answer (score 3):

[DoubleAA's answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/79850/8775) about the correct identity of marror, and the history of the usage of horseradish.

Answer (score 2):

Someone has to nominate [SAH's answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/80380/9682) regarding women in Judaism. It's certainly a sensitive topic, and I think she covered it well. Plus, it's got +27, so it's got something going for it.

Answer (score 2):

[Eliyahu's PTIJ answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/80751/759) for why Esther fined the Jews. This answer exemplifies quality Purim Torah, showing a familiarity with a wide breadth of sources, using multiple subtly flawed translations, and tying together completely unrelated topics.

Answer (score 2):

Double AA's [answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/80402/5323) to [Does Judaism consider women inferior?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/80379/does-judaism-consider-women-inferior/80380#80380) is [also](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4320/5323) an appropriately sensitive treatment of the topic, with greater detail and attention to sources, correcting some false and/or overstated premises of that question. Double AA also puts the question in a different light by doing the math, noting that ~95% of the biblical commandments are also incumbent on women.

The answer also deals specifically with some particular commandments (tefillin, tzitzis, Torah, leading communal prayer) that women are both exempt and discouraged from performing, and provides sources and reasoning for all of them. I think this is a very good answer.

Comment: I know this suggestion comes somewhat little late in the contest. Thinking about it now, if this answer does not get (even part of) this contest's prize, I may have just convinced myself to offer a bounty from my own store of reputation points.

Answer (score 1):

[DanF's answer to What is the bracha for cheesecake or apple pie?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/81124/5275) provides an interesting insight to both the bracha for somewhat common foods, as well as some insight into the discussions of *ikar* and *tafel* and hwo that works in a somewhat unusual situation. This situation, in a sense, more finely defines what we may normally think is *ikar* and *tafel* with some foods. Much of that decision depends on how we, personally, will eat that food, regardless of common eating habits.

Answer (score 1):

[Shoel U'Meishiv's answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/80341/9682), which I feel takes PTIJ to a whole new level. Misapplying Kabbalah for the sake of Purim Torah? That's hardcore [Mishloach Minus](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6305/9682).