# Best answer contest: Third quarter of 5777

Tags: discussion, status-completed, answer-contest

Have you seen (or written) a recent answer on Mi Yodeya that you thought was really great? Let's have a contest to help you tell everyone about it!

This contest has two phases: Nomination and Voting. It is currently in the **Voting** phase.

1. **Nomination** - ending July 1, 2017

   Post an answer to this Meta post containing a link to the Mi Yodeya answer you want to nominate. Answers created in **Nisan - Sivan, 5777 (from March 28, 2017 through June 24, 2017)** are eligible.

   Please link to one answer in each entry. Nominate as many answers as you like in separate answers to this post.

   *When you see a great answer, don't wait; post a link to it here before you forget!*

   Please *do not* vote on any answers to this post during the Nomination phase.
2. **Voting** - July 1, 2017 - July 8, 2017

   During this phase, everyone is invited to vote on the answers to this post however you see fit. Upvote (or downvote, I guess) as many as you like.

   Last-minute nominations are still welcome during the Voting phase.

[image: 300-point Bounty button]

The answer linked in the highest voted answer to this meta post will receive a bounty of 300 points after completion of the event on July 8, 2017. In case of a tie, the distinction will be shared, and the prize will be split.

---

<sup>Concept and words borrowed from [Movies.SE](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/rewards-for-the-best-answer-from-the-4th-quarter-of-2016).</sup>

Comment: At [DoubleAA's suggestion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36938894#36938894), I'm running this one a little differently than the previous ones, by opening up for nominations during (most of) the contest period itself, so that people can nominate great answers as soon as they come across them,

Comment: Locked to end voting.

Answer (score 8):

[Lee](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/2091/lee)'s [answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/83382/759) to [How many halachot are detailed in the Mishneh Torah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/34248/759) exemplifies doing original work and research to deal with a problem, not just searching Google for someone else's work. That's something we should encourage here on Mi Yodeya.

Answer (score 8):

[Tookie345](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/14809/tookie345)'s [self answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/82959/759) to [Which sins are specifically punished with drought?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/82949/759) involved an OP taking info from a comment ("Check out Taanit 7b") and not only looking it up for himself but following up and sharing with the community with a well written answer. That's something we should encourage here on Mi Yodeya.

Answer (score 3):

[Aryeh](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1865/aryeh)'s excellent [answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/82363/759) to [Mizmor L'Toda with Melody](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/52759/759) provides all of what the question sought and more: historical records of the practice, reasons for its demise, and information about its renewal including a link to a full recording of a tune. It is also written clearly (with translations) and is well sourced (with citations).

Answer (score 3):

[Shalom's answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/83492/2) to [Can ground coffee beans or instant coffee be used for b'samim during Havdalah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/83491/can-ground-coffee-beans-or-instant-coffee-be-used-for-bsamim-during-havdalah) does a great job of taking a simple Halacha question, exposing multiple Halachic angles that apply, and explaining how and why Sepharadi and Ashkenazi traditions would treat the case differently, all in accessible language, with an engaging style.

Answer (score 2):

[Isaac Moses' answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/81921/2) to [How to approach saying divrei torah at the shabbos table](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/81881/how-to-approach-saying-divrei-torah-at-the-shabbos-table) provides the benefit of the author's personal experience and is compelling and well-organized. (Bias alert: nominated by its author.)

Answer (score 1):

[mevaqesh's answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/81591/2) to [What is the reason we say שפך חמתך, pour out your wrath?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/81590/what-is-the-reason-we-say-%D7%A9%D7%A4%D7%9A-%D7%97%D7%9E%D7%AA%D7%9A-pour-out-your-wrath/) is a *tour de force*, bringing together numerous opinions from Rishonim and Acharonim. I expect to use it to enhance this part of the Seder next Pesach.

Answer (score 0):

[TrustMeI'mARabbi's answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/81850/2) to [Is there a reason for the change in word order in Vayikra 25:10?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/38007/is-there-a-reason-for-the-change-in-word-order-in-vayikra-2510) nails the answer, bringing commentary and super-commentary to bear, with all sources attributed, linked, and provided in Hebrew and English.