# Best Answer Contest winners! Second quarter of 5777

Tags: discussion, status-completed, answer-contest

Congratulations and Yeyasher Kochachem to the co-winners of the [Best Answer Contest for the second quarter of 5777](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4307/759)!

Here are the original citations, submitted by msh210, mevaqesh, and Isaac Moses, respectively:

- [HodofHod's answer](//judaism.stackexchange.com/a/79713) about the Touro Synagogue's trap door shows a good deal of research into authoritative sources.
- [DoubleAA's answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/79850/8775) about the correct identity of marror, and the history of the usage of horseradish.
- [mevaqesh's answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/80705/2) to [Source that hearing the Megillah does not require Hebrew understanding?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/80703/source-that-hearing-the-megillah-does-not-require-hebrew-understanding) traces the rule in question from the Mishna down to the Shulchan Aruch, providing clear references, quotations with translations, and on-point, succinct explanations along the way. It's an exemplary response to a "what is the source for ..." question.

The winning entries will split the 300-point bounty prize evenly.

[Best answer contest: Third quarter of 5777](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4310/best-answer-contest-third-quarter-of-5777), covering Nisan through Sivan, 5777 (from March 28, 2017 through July 1, 2017), is ***already underway***. If you see a new great answer, please enter it!